# Is unary $\Pi_2$-SUBSETSUM coNP-complete?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, np-hardness, complexity-classes, lo.logic

Consider the following problem:

for given integers $a_1, \ldots, a_{2n}$ and $A$ that are given in unary representation

define is it true that

for every $S \subseteq \{1, ..., 2n \}$ such that $|S|=n$ there exists $H \subseteq S$ such that

$$\sum_{i \in H} a_i = A. $$

This problem belongs to co**NP**. Indeed, for fixed $S$ we can define the existence of required $H$ in polynomial time since there exists a pseudo-polynomial algorithm for SUBSET-SUM.

**Question:** Is this problem co**NP**-complete?

**UPD** I have understood that a hardness result about this problem would give a partial  answer to Stefan Szeider's question that he asked in his paper [Monadic Second Order Logic on Graphs with Local Cardinality Constraints](http://www.kr.tuwien.ac.at/drm/szeider/papers/mso-final.pdf).

At this paper the author generalized Courcelle’s theorem by the following way:

> We consider problems of the following form:  Given a graph $G$ and for each vertexv of $G$ set $\alpha(v)$ of non-negative integers.  The question is whether there exists a set $S$ of vertices or edges of $G$ that
>   (i) satisfies a fixed MSO-expressible property, and
>   (ii)  for  each  vertex $v$ of $G$,  the  number  of  vertices  in $S$ adjacent  to $v$ plus  the number of edges in $S$ incident with $v$ belongs to the set $\alpha(v)$. We call such a problem an MSO problem for graphs with local cardinality constraints,or MSO-LCC problem, for short.

The main result of the paper is the following theorem.

> **Theorem** For every constant $k \ge 1$, every MSO-LCC problem can be solved in polynomial time for graphs of treewidth at most $k$.

It is natural to consider more general question.

> We consider the more general class of Q-MSO-LCC problems where cardinality constraints are applied to second-order variablesthat are arbitrarily quantified (not just existentially as for MSO-LCC problems). We show,  however,  that there exist Q-MSO-LCC problems that are already NP-hard for graphs of treewidth $2$.

However, the example of an NP-hard problem that can be expressed as Q-MSO-LCC requires two alternations of quantifies. We do not know an example of NP-hard problem that can be expressed as Q-MSO-LCC problem with one alternation of quantifies.

I claim that  unary $\Pi_2$-SUBSETSUM can be expressed as Q-MSO-LCC problem with one alternation of quantifies.  For given $a_1, a_2, a_3,..., a_{2n}$ and
$A$ 
consider the graph with $a_1, a_2, a_3,..., a_{2n} + 2n + 2$ vertices:
[image]

Now let $X_1$ be a set of vertices that is some subset of vertices of
the second (children of $R$) and the third levels with the following
property: If a vertex $v$ of the second level belongs to $X_1$ then all
children of $v$ belong to $X_1$. We require that $X_1$ contains $n$ vertices
of the second level (so, $R$ has $n$ neighborhoods in $X_1$).

Let $X_2$ be some subset of $X_1$ with the same property: if a vertex $v$ of
the second level belongs to $X_2$ then all children of $v$ belong to $X_2$.
We require that $X_2$ contains $A$ vertices of the third level (so, $T$
has $A$ neighborhoods in $X_2$).

I claim that $(a_1,..., a_{2n}, A)$ belongs to $\Pi_2$-unary-subsetsum iff
for all $X_1$ there exists $X_2$ with all properties written above.